# An HTML code analyzer, like firebug, for outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, firebug

Designing email templates for outlook can be a real pain. Other email providers are normally online and we can check the rendered page to see what changes the email provider has done to our emails (Like GMail, replacing `height`s with `min-height`s).

Does anyone know any source code analyzer (something like Firebug or Chrome developer tools) for MS Outlook? or someway to know what changes outlook has made to your code and styles.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: I was thinking about the same, but for thunderbird

Comment: Yes, it will be good for thunderbird too, but unfortunately outlook is the one with the most irrational bugs and problems.

Comment: I don't know anything that could help, but I sympathise entirely. Outlook 2007+ uses the *awful* MS Word HTML rendering engine.

Comment: @harley Thanks. Yeah, I really wonder if Microsoft employees can actually use their own products.

Comment: @Auxiliary *http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C12/outlook-preview* - This has some info at the top you might find interesting

Comment: @harley Thanks for the link. 
I've heard people saying things like, outlook changes some attributes and styles to some other things. I wonder what they use to find this out.

Comment: @Auxiliary To tell the truth, I use mailchimp and it sorts all these things out for you almost before you have started. This (http://templates.mailchimp.com/) could help, even if you don't use that service

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't really anything like that out there.
What I typically do is use a service such as

- http://www.campaignmonitor.com/
- http://litmus.com/

These allow you to take screen shots of how your email appears on different browsers/email clients/phones and then it is pretty much trial and error from there to get it working perfectly.

Comment: +1 I've used both of them but sometimes it's all about the trial and error part that consumes a lot of time for a small change. Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: I know it sucks. I found that making a boilerplate for my email templates is useful. Then you have a starting point with some of the common issues already fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Save the file as a html from outlook and load into chrome/firefox...

Comment: Let me elaborate the reason behind the downvotes here. The issue OP was referring to is related to _how outlook interprets the HTML_. If you pull raw source from Outlook and put into Chrome it's the same as if you opened the original HTML sent to Outlook at the first place. Same like Chome's View Source and "Inspect" sources differ, Outlook's raw source and the actual _interpreted_ source (the one which OP seeks to get access to) will differ. For example, Outlook will disregard background images. If there was "Inspect" in Outlook, you would not see those in rendered HTML.